# does lmdb support "recno" type, or workalike?

Tags: berkeley-db, lmdb

I'm playing w/ lmdb (coming from a BDB background) and wondering if lmdb supports "recno" style operation ? "recno" (record number) is a logical indexing method where the 20th record might be deleted, and a *new* record becomes the 20th record, or a record is inserted after 7, and the  following records previously known as 8 - n  become 9 - n+1.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No.

(filler for 30 character minimum)